# jquery - change background color of select options when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this html code

```
<p> 
  <label for="contact">Contact name<span class="required"> *</span></label>
  <select name="contact" id="contact" onClick="clearSelect(this,'contact')">
  <option value="">Select Contact</option>
  <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact): ?>
<option value="<?php htmlout($contact['id']); ?>" 
    <?php if ($contact['id'] == $contactID) echo ' selected="selected"';                                
    ?>><?php htmlout($contact['name']); ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>    
 </p>
```

and this jQuery function

```
function clearSelect(thisfield, id) {

$j("#" + id).css("background-color","#FFF");
$j("#" + id).css("border","1px solid #CCCCCC");
$j("#" + id).css("color","#000000");
}
```

When I click the select book the background of the select box changes to white but the drop down list stays the same color until you scroll down it.

Any ideas how to change all the option background colors to white when the select box is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the `.css()` method combined with `.children()` and `.andSelf()` (so it affects the select and the options):

```
function clearSelect(thisfield, id) {
    $j("#" + id).children().andSelf().css({"background-color":"#FFF", 
        "border":"1px solid #CCCCCC",
        "color":"#000000"});
}
```

Also, there's no need to call the `.css()` method multiple times, you can do it a single time with a map of the property-value sets...

Comment: Thanks for your help. i replace my function with yours but now when i click the select box nothing happens. The background doesnt change.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo (`chilren` instead of `children`), just in case I changed your code a little made a to test it http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/mXrSd/2/

Comment: ok i got it children was spelt wrong. :) thanks again for your help

Comment: jsfiddle.net/darkajax/mXrSd/2  this works fine in chrome but how come it puts a border around each option in firefox

Comment: @user1460609 Maybe set the `border` on only the `<select>` element and then set the `background-color` and `color` on everything

Answer (score 1):

i dont want a border on each of the options in the select box so i changed the function to this

```
function clearSelect(thisfield, id) {
$j("#" + id).children().andSelf().css({"background-color":"#FFF", 
    "border":"1px solid #CCCCCC",
    "color":"#000000"});
$j("#" + id).children().css({
    "border":"0px solid #CCCCCC"
    });
}
```

How come this doesnt work again?? when i click the select box now
the options menu appears but the background color only changes when i hover over each of them.
This is very strange.